# jQuery: Date Range Picker: refresh page after selecting datepicker and keeping the selected date after page reload

Tags: jquery, datepicker

So i have this picker:

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/

this demo

http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/daterangepicker_v2/

I want to refresh page after selecting datepicker and keeping the selected date after page reload.
I have seach solve and apply to my code. But still the same.

This partly my code

```
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Themeroller-Ready jQuery UI Range Picker</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/daterangepicker.jQuery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ui.daterangepicker.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css" type="text/css" title="ui-theme" />
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function(){
              $('input').daterangepicker({
                  arrows:true
                } );

         });

    </script>
```

I really thanks and apreciate for who solve my problem. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't understand why you'd need to keep the data after a page refresh, your best bet is to use cookies to solve the problem.

This would require to use an event-handler (such as onchange) attached to your datepicker input textbox.

```
<input type="text" onchange="setCookie();" name="datepicker">
```

This way, whenever the user changes the data (eg: selects a date), the javascript function setCookie is called. The function would then have to store the date that was picked by setting a cookie ([example](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/settinga.htm)).

Once you have your cookie set, you have to make sure that your input is pre-populated with whatever value was last stored in the cookie. This means reading the cookie ([example](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/readinga.htm))  and the setting the value of the input either through an `value=""` tag or jQuery `$("input").val("")`.

Comment: and then how to refresh page?

Comment: In javascript: `location.reload();`